# Is there a way to make glossary entries whitout printing this entry as is in the text?

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I am using the glossary to make a listing of symbols in my file, but I got the following problem: some times symbols appear in the text with very specific arguments, one example is the following:

```
$$\bigsqcup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} A_t$$
```

But when appearing in the glossary I would like this to appear as:

```
$$\bigsqcup_{x \in X}$$
```

with a generic element `$x$` and set `$X$`.

I have tried to do this by putting the `\gls` call into a `\phantom` command, i.e. `$\phantom{\gls{disuni}}$` and removing the occupied space with `\hspace*`, but this doesn't generate a entry in the glossary, I have also tryied changing the color of the `\gls` to white with `\changecolor{white}` and removing the occupied space again with `\hspace*`, but because `\gls` appears to generate a link, in my file this link is made blue, so the `\changecolor{white}` has no effect in practice.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\hypersetup{
%pagebackref=true,
pdftitle={\@title}, 
pdfauthor={\@author},
pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{trabalho acadêmico}, 
colorlinks=true,            % false: boxed links; true: colored links
linkcolor=blue,             % color of internal links
citecolor=blue,             % color of links to bibliography
filecolor=magenta,              % color of file links
urlcolor=blue,
bookmarksdepth=4
}

\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=use,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

$$ \bigsqcup_{t \in \mathbb{R} } \newglossaryentry{disun}{name={\ensuremath{\bigsqcup\limits_{x \in  X} }},sort={disun},description={ Disjoint union indexed by $X$  $\hspace{0.3pt}$, $\hspace{2pt}$},type={symbols}}\textcolor{white}{\gls{disun}} \hspace*{-10pt} $$

$$ \bigsqcup_{t' \in \mathbb{R} } \newglossaryentry{disuun}{name={\ensuremath{\bigsqcup\limits_{y \in  Y} }},sort={disuun},description={ Disjoint union indexed by $Y$  $\hspace{0.3pt}$, $\hspace{2pt}$},type={symbols}}\phantom{\gls{disuun}} \hspace*{-10pt} $$

\printglossary[type=symbols,title={Symbols List}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please use backticks for inline code. Note that you shouldn't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: `\glsadd{disuni}`

Comment: @DaiBowen yes it does! Thanks!